# 404 with Angular params route

Tags: angular

I have a quite strange issue with params routing in Angular. If I code it in Stackblitz, it works, but locally I get error 404.

app.module.ts

```
import { RoutingModule } from './routing.module';
import { ConfirmEmailComponent } from './confirm-email/confirm-email.component';
 
@NgModule({
  imports:      [
   RoutingModule,
   ],
  declarations: [ ConfirmEmailComponent],
)}
```

routing.module.ts

```
import { ConfirmEmailComponent } from './confirm-email/confirm-email.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "activate/:uid/:token", component: ConfirmEmailComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

In ConfirmEmailComponent

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient, 
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.uid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("uid");
        this.token = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("token");
    }
```

I also tried with subscribe, but I get the same problem. Other routes work just fine.

So I go to root/activate/a/b and I got error "http://localhost:4200/activate/ab/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

If I add to router the following line, there is no error 404, but of course no uid or token.

```
    { path: "activate", component: ConfirmEmailComponent },
```

I don't understand what changes between Stackblitz (https://angular-tufqi9.stackblitz.io/) and local. Any idea?

EDIT:
I made some supplementary tests.
If I type the address in the url-bar of my browser, still the same problem. So http://localhost:4200/activate/abc/edf.

But, if I link a button to either

```
this.router.navigate(['activate', "abc", "edf"]);
```

or

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('activate/abc/edf');
```

Then it works. Strangely, if I make F5, the problem comes back.

What is the difference between Url typing in browser and this.router.navigate?

Comment: `RoutingModule`... is this a typo or you really forgot the `.forRoot(...)` in your setup?

Comment: edited, no it is inside, otherwise the other paths wouldn't work I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

check your index.html
change your base href to:

```html
  <base href="/">
```